# Background image for media screen not displaying whole image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my site responsive and I cannot get my pages background image that covers 85% of the screen to display the entire image. It just shows a very small portion of it. What am I doing wrong? If it helps, my site is sundayfundayleague.com .

I'm attempting to do this..

```
.indexgraypage {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.homeimg {
    background-image: url("/images/bright_lights_smallest.jpg");
    width: 80%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: try with background-size: 100%;

Comment: Is it showing just a thin horizontal strip of the image?

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yes, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi That didn't help.

Comment: The issue is likely that `height: 100%` is not doing what you expect. Inspect the `.homeimg` element and see how tall it is.

Comment: Nevermind everyone. I made a stupid mistake and forgot to enter.. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0">` Thanks everyone.

Comment: darn . so this question has been solved. I announced this question closed.

Comment: Hey everyone. This same image is doing this on another page now. I have the view port on it, but the last small part of the page is not being covered by the images. The page is on the register page. sundayfundayleague.com/register.php

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome and Firefox on OSX.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher I have a note 4 and maybe it is because I have more height to my phone but the bottom is white and doesn't show the image